# How to add jar files and compile using command prompt? (Error: A JNI error has occured,Please Check your Installation)

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, jsonexception

I forked one project from github and when i want to run it gives error. I added `org.json` jar file to `jdk\lib` and also set the Path variable to it. I compiled code but it got no errors but when i run it i get exception as follows : (and I am running it using command prompt)

> ```
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/json/JSONExceptio n
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.json.JSONException
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> ```
>
> ... 7 more

Comment: You should add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody can reproduce your problem and hopefully help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add required jar to classpath like this:

1. For *nix-like systems:

   ```
   export CLASSPATH=<path-to-app>/myapp.jar:<path-to-app>/lib/json.jar:.
   java MyApp
   ```
2. For Windows:

   ```
   set CLASSPATH=<path-to-app>/myapp.jar;<path-to-app>/lib/json.jar;.
   java MyApp
   ```

...or via manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyApp
Class-Path: /lib/json.jar
```

Comment: @Pratik, not **PATH** but **CLASSPATH**. First is used by system for file-finding, secon - by JVM for **dependencies** finding, like yours org.json.jar

Comment: also, you can try to extract contents of org.json.jar by some unzip program and add them into yours main `.jar`, but that not always working (for ex., if jar's are signed)